# How to perform an action only on the first line?

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

```
sed 's/.\(.*\)/\1/' myfile
```

Say myfile contains:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

I want to remove the first character only from the first line but the above removes it from all the line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe `sed '1s/.\(.*\)/\1/' myfile`?

Comment: Capturing groups slows down the regular expressions. Better do it without them: `sed '1s/.//' myfile`.

Answer (score 4):

can also use awk: `awk 'NR==1 {sub(/./,"")} 1'`

Answer (score 3):

`tail` can read from a ***byte*** offset, so if your file uses only *single-byte characters* (typically UTF-8 ASCII), this will work.

It depends on your situaton, whether it is improtant to you or not, but `tail` is faster than `sed`... probably becaue *sed* needs to process each line  inndividually, ... But don't use it where there is any chance of the first **character** using more than one byte.

```
tail -c +2 "file"
```

From `man tail`

> -c, --bytes=N
>                 output the last N bytes; alternatively, use +N to output bytes 
>                 starting with the Nth of each file